# How to extract and add backspaces to JSON datas in react native?

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I have this JSON :

```
  "data"{
   "names": ["alfred","anthony","mary","john"],
   "cities": ["nyc","paris", "berlin"]
   }
```

I want this, but the array heigth inside the JSON will depend on how many datas are inside:

```
names : alfred, 
        anthony, 
        mary, 
        john
cities : nyc, 
        paris, 
        berlin
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want array values as a string where each word separated by comma?

Comment: I edited. I want each word separated by a backspace

Comment: You can try `Array#join` over the arrays to get the result, example  `names.join(",\n")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data ={
   "names": ["alfred","anthony","mary","john"],
   "cities": ["nyc","paris", "berlin"]
   }

data.names.join('\n');
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include details on why and how this solves OP's problem